# Frappe: What is the difference between short, default and Long queue

Tags: erpnext, frappe

Apart from timeout as mentioned in the frappe document, 300s for short and default and 1500s for long queue. Is there any more difference between these 3 types of queues. And, when should one prefer one over other as short and default queue seems to have same timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Each Queue has a number of workers assigned. Generally short queues have more worker threads and Long has fewer threads.

Apart from timeout, you may decide based on how much concurrency is requried.